# Unresolved external 'std::char_traits<char>::assign(char *, unsigned int, char)'

Tags: string, stl, linker, c++builder

I'm working on bringing some old code forward to the C++Builder XE7 environment. When I compile a small standalone tool with the low-level i/o library, I get this error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits<char>::assign(char *, unsigned int, char)' referenced from <library>|mydate
```

The mydate class isn't horribly complex, and only one function really uses an STL class, string (surprise!). If I commented out the contents of one function, the error went away. That code is pasted below, but before you look at it, a few things to note:

1. This code was written a VERY long time ago. I inherited it in the C++ Builder 6 development environment. I brought it forward to C++ Builder 2010 a few years ago, where it seemed to work just fine.
2. Part of the reason it does things the way it does is that this code is also compiled for a non-VCL environment. Everything is standardized on char * because it was portable.
3. My first guess was that this was a wide/narrow string issue. I think it should all be narrow strings, but I wasn't able to make everything explicitly narrow in a manner that the compiler liked.
4. In this case, I found a way to work around the issue by letting TDateTime do the formatting for me, but there are other cases in the much larger application where string is used (instead of AnsiString), either because the author was using other STL classes (map, etc), or he was using it to host a character array that he was wandering through with a pointer (generally doing manual tokenizing similar to the example below).
5. I do not have the luxury of bringing all of this code up to 21st century C++ standards. I'm sure there're better ways of doing many of these things, but I do not have enough time available to rewrite/update the millions of lines of code in this product suite. My goal here is to understand why this code now causes a problem, and how to fix it with as little change as possible.
6. As far as I can tell this method isn't even called by the application.
7. The class name has been changed to protect the guilty.

So, here it is. Can you tell me why this would cause the above link error?

Thank you so much!

-Karen

```
string myDate::Format(const char* format) const
{
    string output;

    if (julian == 0)
        return output;

    while (format[0] != '\0')
    {
        if (format[0] == 'm')
        {
            if (format[1] == 'm')
            {
                if (format[2] == 'm')
                {
                    if (format[3] == 'm')
                    {
                        // mmmm Full name of month.
                        output += CMonthName();
                        format += 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // mmm Three letter abbreviation of month.
                        output += CMonthAbbr();
                        format += 3;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // mm Two digit month (zero fill).
                    const char* ptr = CMonth();
                    if (ptr[1] == '\0')
                        output += '0';
                    output += ptr;
                    format += 2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // m One or two digit month (blank fill). 
                const char* ptr = CMonth();
                if (ptr[1] == '\0')
                    output += '0';
                output += ptr;
                format += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (format[0] == 'd')
        {
            if (format[1] == 'd')
            {
                if (format[2] == 'd')
                {
                    if (format[3] == 'd')
                    {
                        // dddd Full name of day of week. 
                        output += CDayName();
                        format += 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ddd Three letter abbreviation of day of week.
                        output += CDayAbbr();
                        format += 3;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // dd Two digit day of month (zero fill). 
                    const char *ptr = CDay();
                    if (ptr[1] == '\0')
                        output += '0';
                    output += ptr;
                    format += 2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // d One or two digit day of month (blank fill). 
                const char *ptr = CDay();
                if (ptr[1] == '\0')
                    output += ' ';
                output += ptr;
                format += 1;
            }
        }
        else if (format[0] == 'y')
        {
            if (format[1] == 'y')
            {
                if (format[2] == 'y')
                {
                    if (format[3] == 'y')
                    {
                        // yyyy Four digit year. 
                        output += CYear();
                        format += 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // yyy Not valid (use \y\y\y for yyy) 
                        return string();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // yy Two digit year (zero fill). 
                    const char *ptr = CYearAbbr();
                    if (ptr[1] == '\0')
                        output += '0';
                    output += ptr;
                    format += 2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // y Not valid (use \y or y) 
                return string();
            }
        }
        else if (format[0] == '\\')
        {
            if (format[1] != '\0')
            {
                output += format[1];
                format += 2;
            }
        }
        else if (format[0] == ';')
        {
            // ignore rest of format text
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            output += format[0];
            format += 1;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: As you mention, it is probably a `char` versus `wchar_t` issue. But that gets configured on the project options, so you should probably check and post here what options you have there. You can check the `C++ (Shared Options)` section and see what _TCHAR is mapped to. Maybe you just need to specify there `char` instead of `wchar_t` which is the default for new projects, IIRC.

Comment: It is set to `wchar_t`, which is what we need to interact with the VCL controls we use in our UI. As I understand it, that SHOULD only affect `System::String`, and not `string` (from the Dinkumware stl). At least that seemed to be the case in CBB2010. If I'm wrong about that, I'm about to experience a tremendous amount of pain.

Comment: You could try changing it to char and see what happens. But if you are using the String type (which is an alias only) and accessing its bytes with `.c_str()` and assuming it's a `char *` then yes, it will probably be somewhat difficult to move everything. One possible option is to NOT use `System::String`, but `AnsiString`. That way you will get a `char *` buffer when accesed via `.c_str()`, and if you assign from the UI the conversion happens automagically between UnicodeString and AnsiString.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rodrigo, that's what I tried to do without success. I was hoping someone might have a suggestion as to why this no longer works, so I wouldn't keep rewriting it blindly.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In E:\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\include\boost_1_39\boost\test\utils\basic_cstring\basic_cstring.hpp, in the section assignment operators, add the line:

basic_cstring&  assign( basic_cstring<char> const& s ) { *this = basic_cstring<char>( s.begin(), s.end() ); return *this; }

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a very similar issue to this and figured I'd share my solution

Under Projection Options > C++ Linker I enabled Link with Dynamic RTL and it started linking happily for me