# C++ Builder 11 linker problem - Unresolved external 'std::char_traits<char>::assign(char *, unsigned int, char)

Tags: c++, linker-errors, assign, c++builder-6, char-traits

I'm trying to revive an old project in C++Builder 11.3 (initially written in C++Builder 6). I'm using the 'classic' Borland compiler, which solves the `wchar_t` problem. But I'm getting this error:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'std::char_traits<char>::assign(char *, unsigned int, char)' referenced from (...)\CRYPTLIB_BDS.LIB|integer

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148474/), to which one of the answers is to enable "Link with Dynamic RTL". I don't want to do that, I need to link it statically.

[Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666438/) suggests setting the `-fno-inline-functions` flag in the compiler, which didn't work either.

I tried to write the definition of the function, but then I got this error:

> [bcc32 Error] File1.cpp(5): E2171 Body has already been defined for function 'char_traits<char>::assign(char *,unsigned int,char)'

Does anyone have any idea why this problem occurs, and hopefully what to do to get the project to compile and link properly?

**The main problem** is that the linker doesn't seem to find the definition of the `std::char_traits<char>::assign(char *, unsigned int, char)` function, but when I create the other body - the error shows up.

Comment: Did you recompile Cryptlib with the new compiler?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be the system memory architecture. When I recompiled the CRYPTLIB_BDS.LIB lib 64-bit configuration on bcc32 compiler the project started working. Also what I found is that every higher version of RAD Studio than 10 fails.